# How to zoomToExtent with useSpatialIndex = false?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have some problems with extents. I use Openlayers and a Mapserver WFS layer, with geojson as output format.
I need to get my features ordered in my geojson, so I set useSpatialIndex=false in the source vector.

But the problem is that I want to fit zoom with the size of the map, for different screen sizes.
So, is there a way to adjust zoom to layer extent without the function getExtent ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it by iterating through the features

```
  var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
  source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
    ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent(), extent);
  });
  console.log(extent);
```